# .htaccess redirect from /subfolder/file to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect every URL that requests a file in /subfolder, for example: example.com/subfolder/food/apple.pdf -> example.com

I tried creating a .htaccess inside /subfolder that contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/.*$ / [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, without success. Is there a way to achieve this?
apple.pdf and all files inside the /subfolder do not exist anymore (that's why I need a redirect)

Comment: Either place that rule inside a dynamic configuation file inside the root folder or remove the ``subfolder/`` prefix from the rules. Currently the rule will only get applied to URLs like `https://example.com/subfolder/subfolder/food/apple.pdf`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That makes sense. I've copied the .htaccess-file one folder above, but the redirect does not work. Maybe the CMS has some pre-defined rules somewhere that override the rules of the .htaccess. But that is out of the scope of this question.